Cutting across the graph of a function with a line through the origin
I have a question about a conclusion that is used in a proof/an example (Angus Taylor, General Theory of Functions and Integration, p. 304). We consider the set $L:=\{f\colon(0,1]\to\mathbb{R}:f(x)=ax, a∈\mathbb{R}\}$.
There is my problem: I take a non-negative function $g\colon(0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$, that is not an element of $L$. Then the author states that there must exist a function $h∈L$ and two distinct points $x_1,x_2∈(0,1]$, such that $h(x_1)<g(x_1),g(x_2)<h(x_2)$. Then the proof goes on.
If I draw a picture to this statement I would say this statement is true, such a function can always be found, but I am not able to show the existence rigorously. I thought maybe it can be shown by contradiction: if for all functions and all distinct points you show that inequalities are not true unless $g$ is in $L$, but this didn't work.
Do you have another idea? Thank you!!

The title "Conclusion in a proof" is totally uniformative. I'll edit with a better one. Feel free to edit again if you have an idea for an even better title.

That’s true. Thank you!


Take $x_1$ arbitrarily, and set $a_1 = g(a_1) > 0$. Then I first define $f_1$ via
\begin{equation}
f_1(x) = \frac{a_1}{x_1}x.
\end{equation}
By assumption $g \neq h_0$, so there exists $x_2$ such that $g(x_2) \neq f_0(x_2) = a_1x_2$. As before I set $a_2 = g(x_2)$ and I define $f_2$ via
\begin{equation}
f_2(x) = \frac{a_2}{x_2}x.
\end{equation}
By construction
\begin{equation}
\frac{a_1}{x_1} \neq \frac{a_2}{x_2}
\end{equation}
and for the sake of the argument assume that
\begin{equation}
\frac{a_1}{x_1} > \frac{a_2}{x_2}.
\end{equation}
Otherwise we switch the indices.
Now finally I choose $h \in L$ corresponding to some $a$ between these two fractions. Then we get
\begin{equation}
h(x_1) = ax_1 < \frac{a_1}{x_1}x_1 = a_1 = g(x_1)
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
h(x_x) = ax_2 > \frac{a_2}{x_2}x_2 = a_2 = g(x_2)
\end{equation}
I hope I did not mess up some indices.
All the best

Hello! Really cool, thank you! The idea to work with two linear functions to construct the third that satisfies the condition is a very neat trick!
I think there are some typos with the indices, but that doesn’t matter, I understand the idea.

Glad that it makes sense. Maybe I'll go index hunting later. :D
